# What's the purpose of session.use_trans_sid?

Tags: php, session, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php session.use_trans_sid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745984/php-session-use-trans-sid)

This PHP directive `session.use_trans_sid` is generally frowned upon is disabled by default. I don't understand the real purpose of this directive or why is it included in PHP if it's recommended to be turned off.

What are situations where in you would actually want this feature enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If Cookies are disabled on the client, PHP will append a session ID in the GET-Request of links to enable persistent $_SESSION-Data. However, Search-Engines will rank your site lower due to the Parameter being always present.

Beside that, I do not know of any other problems with enabling the option - which will make your site accessible, even if cookies are disabled on the client side.

Comment: So if `session.use_trans_sid` and cookies are both disabled then sessions will not work?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, but I think so - however, if you overwrite the session handler or add the sessionid yourself to all links, it will still work.