# PHP AJAX post not seeing existing $_COOKIE['x']

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I know this is a common problem and I've ran into it before and was able to fix it but I can't figure this one out so I need some extra sets of eyes/brains please.

Here's the exact scenario I witnessed while stepping through with a debugger:

```
[home page load]
Session::Load()
$session_uid = (new) d149f...
$row = false

[login page load]
Session::Load()
$_COOKIE['x'] (found/existing) d149f...
$session_uid = d149f...
$row = data

$_COOKIE['x'] d149f...

[login page login submit] // <--- submitted via Ajax code above
Session::Load()
$_COOKIE['x'] == null // <--- Here's the problem
$session_uid = (new) 4bd87...
$row = false

$_COOKIE['x'] d149f... (original)
+
$_COOKIE['x'] 4bd87... (new created from ajax post)
```

If I use the jQuery below to submit a login form using AJAX the server does not see the existing `$_COOKIE['x']` when handling the post, which is causing our session handler to not recognize the visitor and create a new session instead and adds another `$_COOKIE['x']` to the browser.

Without using AJAX the server reads the browser's `$_COOKIE['x']` properly and recognizes the visitor. The cookie Domain and Path appear to be correct, I'm not doing any cross-domain requests either.

`$_COOKIE['x'] Domain: localhost Path: /myApp`

PHP code that is ran on every request is below. I've ran xdebug and stepped through the request and it does indeed go through the code properly on both browser and AJAX requests, only the AJAX request returns `$_COOKIE['x']` is `null` thus creates a new session.

`if ( empty( $_COOKIE['x'] ) ) { // new sess`

Login form AJAX code:

```
$( '#btnLogin' ).on( "click", function() {
    console.debug( 'Click' );
    // Btn
    var btn = $( this );
    // Form data
    var frm = $( '#' + btn.val() );
    // Validate
    if ( !frm.valid() ) {
      return false;
    }
    btn.prop( 'disabled', true ).html( 'Please wait...' );
    var frmData = frm.serializeArray();

    // Ajax execute
    var go = $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo CONTROLLER; ?>/ajax',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: frmData
    } ).done( function( results ) {
      console.debug( 'Done' );
      console.debug( results );
      // Handle Results
      if ( results['status'] === 'OK'
              && results['message']['status'] === 'active')
      {
        $( '#user_login_results' ).html( "<span class='alert alert-success'>Success! Click <a href='#' onClick='document.location.reload(true)'>here</a> to reload.</span><p></p>" );
        btn.html( 'Success!' );
<?php
$return = 'login';
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST[ 'return' ] ) ) {
  $return = htmlentities( $_REQUEST[ 'return' ] );
}
?>

        location.href = '<?php echo CONTROLLER; ?>/en/<?php echo $return; ?>';
      }
      else
      {
        console.debug( results );
        $( '#user_login_results' ).html( "<span class='alert alert-error'>Please check your username and passphrase and try again.</span><p></p>" );
        btn.prop( "disabled", false ).html( "Try Again &raquo;" );
      }
    } ).fail( function( msg ) {
      // Error results
      console.debug( msg );
      $( '#user_login_results' ).append( "<span class='alert alert-error'>Error! Please try again later.</span><p></p>" );
      btn.html( 'Error!' ).removeClass( 'btn-primary' ).addClass( 'btn-danger' );
    } ).always( function() {
      $( "body" ).scrollTop( $( "#result" ) );
    } );
  } );
```

Comment: Maybe this anwser can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745984/php-session-use-trans-sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I guess it was the Path of the `setcookie` after all, changing it from the default to "/" explicitly fixed the problem immediately.

Old: `setcookie( $cookie_name, $session_uid);`

New: `setcookie( $cookie_name, $session_uid, time()+60*60, '/');`